# How to manage a multiple dates in a single column?

Tags: excel

I have data example an organizations,

which consists sl.no, name of organization, facility type, latitude, longitude starting date of facility.My problem is for particular facility i had two or more starting dates, now i want to store  those multiple dates in single file, how is it possible?
my data is now in excel, i want to make shape file now..